# IIS installed new SSL certificate, set bindings to use it because old certificate carries on been used

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I installed a new SSL certificate, it shows in the "Server Certificates" pane as the correct domain name and expring in Oct 24.
For the site bindings I select this new SSL certificate instead of the one that is about to expire in a few days time.

This is something I have done for other domains many times without any problems, but this time whenever I visit the site in a browser it just keeps saying the SSL is going to expire in a few days, its just ignoring the new certificate and carry on using old one.

I restarted the web site and restarted the app pool, made no difference.

I even removed the bindings for the domain all together so the website wasn't working for a few seconds and then re-added them using new SSL cert, but it still carries on using old one.
I daren't delete the old SSL in case the site stops working all together.

Comment: Is your browser caching it?  Try the private window (or whatever its called on your browser).

Comment: How is the web site published? If this is done through a reverse proxy or something like that, the certificate needs to be updated there too.

Comment: The browser caching it isn't the problem, I tried incognito mode and using browsers on other computers that haven't visited the site before. There isn't a reverse proxy, the website is published using Web Deploy within Visual Studio.
The website has lots of domains binding to it and whenever I have updated the ssl cert for the other domains in the past it all worked fine, didn't need to even restart the app pool those times.

Comment: And I tried using SSL labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and it shows the old certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution but a workaround - I changed the binding to not work on SNI, it is the only website on that IP address so doesn't need SNI, and then it started using the new SSL.